# Is there a way to have a rule in one object that references properties from a different object?

Tags: jsonschema

I could not find any examples of this so I'm assuming it's not possible, but want to confirm.

I have a main schema that references other schemas:
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/4aLvXa4I

```
{
  "$defs": {
    "mainSchema": {
      "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
      "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectOne": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/objectOne"
        },
        "objectTwo": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/objectTwo"
        }
      }
    },
    "objectOne": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "checkThisValue": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "objectTwo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "whenSettingThisValue": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref": "#/$defs/mainSchema"
}
```

I want to define this rule:

```
IF objectOne.checkThisValue == one 
THEN objectTwo.whenSettingThisValue MUST == A
Same for two=>B and three=>C
```

Is this possible somehow? How do I reference objectOne properties inside of objectTwo?

### Edit

I tried to create an if rule for objectTwo that references objectOne here, but my syntax is wrong because it's not working. `whenSettingThisValue` is set to `C` and it's saying valid when it should be invalid: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/NNjEIhWW

```
    "objectTwo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "whenSettingThisValue": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "objectOne": {
            "checkThisValue": {
              "const": "one"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "objectTwo": {
            "whenSettingThisValue": {
              "const": "A"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I also tried using a oneOf rule in `mainSchema` where both the subschemas are used, but it is not working either (this example should be invalid): https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/WkmMasDC

```
"mainSchema": {
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "objectOne": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/objectOne"
    },
    "objectTwo": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/objectTwo"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectOne": {
          "checkThisValue": {
            "const": "one"
          }
        },
        "objectTwo": {
          "whenSettingThisValue": {
            "const": "A"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

### Solution

Per answer my OneOf rule was malformed. This correctly checks a value in one object is set in response to another. I thought because I was referencing them in another schema with `$ref` I would have to do something special, but I don't.

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/HcVhrShk

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectOne": {
          "properties": {
            "checkThisValue": {
              "const": "one"
            }
          }
        },
        "objectTwo": {
          "properties": {
            "whenSettingThisValue": {
              "const": "A"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectOne": {
          "properties": {
            "checkThisValue": {
              "const": "two"
            }
          }
        },
        "objectTwo": {
          "properties": {
            "whenSettingThisValue": {
              "const": "B"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. There is an `if`/`then`/`else` construct which takes schemas as its arguments, so you can define a rule "if property A exists with value X, then property B must exist with value Y" etc.

There are some examples here:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else

edit:
in your re-edit, change the `oneOf` clause to this:

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectOne": {
          "properties": {
            "checkThisValue": {
              "const": "one"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "objectTwo": {
          "properties": {
            "whenSettingThisValue": {
              "const": "A"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The examples I seen have the objects nested in the same schema. How do I reference non nested objects/schemas?

Comment: I updated my question with a more accurate example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @red888, I think, then you need to specify the relationship (via `if` or whatever) in the parent object, not in the `objectOne` or `objectTwo`. Will this answer help you: [“json schema field required based on value of nested field”](/q/41285972)?

Comment: @Sasha in my second attempt under EDIT I try to do that. I added a oneOf rule to `mainSchema` which references both subschemas. Hopefully it's just a dumb syntax mistake I missing?

Comment: @red888, you're doing something weird there: `oneOf` with a single subitem is by definition equivalent to just that subitem. You need `if` (or `allOf`+`if`), not `oneOf`. Could you please look [here](/a/70707661), does that help you? (If no, I'll write a separate answer.)

Comment: @red88 I've edited my answer. The syntax you had in your edit was wrong - you were missing a "properties" keyword in between the two nested property names, and you need to put your two possible conditions in separate `oneOf` clauses.

Comment: Outside the scope of this question, but if your rule sets get big is there a way to ref oneOf or anyOf rules located in another file? Like this, where `oneOfRules.json` is a local file in the same folder? `"oneOf": {"$ref": "oneOfRules.json"}`